# Websocket is unable to establish a connection

Tags: java, struts2, websocket

I have the following code to send push notifications to browser, once I run the application get the EJB started and in console it shows in timeout, send etc.

But the Firefox shows it could not establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:8080/Notifications.

**JavaScript function**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
             var wsocket;
      function connect() {
          wsocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/Notifications");
          alert("got connected");
          wsocket.onmessage = onMessage;
      }
      function onMessage(evt) {
          alert(evt);
          var arraypv = evt;
                    alert("array" + arraypv);
          document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = arraypv[0];
      }
      alert("window" + connect);
      window.addEventListener("load", connect, false);
        </script>
```

**Struts mapping**

```
    <action name="Notifications" class="com.example.controller.Notifications">

    </action>
```

**Notifications Class**

```
@ServerEndpoint("/Notifications")
public class Notifications {

   static Queue<Session> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();

   public static void send() {
       System.err.println("send");
       String msg = "Here is the message";
      try {
         /* Send updates to all open WebSocket sessions */
         for (Session session : queue) {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText(msg);
         }
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    @OnOpen
public void openConnection(Session session) {
    System.err.println("in open connection");
    queue.add(session);
}

@OnClose
public void closedConnection(Session session) {
    System.err.println("in closed connection");
    queue.remove(session);
}

@OnError
public void error(Session session, Throwable t) {
    System.err.println("in error");
    queue.remove(session);
}
```

**PriceVolumeBean class**

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class PriceVolumeBean {
@Resource TimerService tservice;
private Random random;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.err.println("in init");
        random = new Random();
        tservice.createIntervalTimer(1000, 1000, new TimerConfig());
    }

    @Timeout
    public void timeout() {
        System.err.println("in timeout");
        Notifications.send();
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: what library are you using on the server?

Comment: @user2310289 I am using javax.websocket-api 1.0

Comment: do you add the session to the queue on `onOpen`  I can not see this code.

Comment: @user2310289 yes sorry I missed those, question is updated

Comment: I doubt it but, is there any conflict between struts "Notifications" and Endpoint "Notifications" ?  Also is it just Firefox that is having this issue?

Answer (score 0):

when you deploy

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>   
</dependency>
```

make this provided.